# Evaluate automake variable only once

Tags: makefile, automake

We are using `automake` & `autoconf` to build our multi-package software. I was wondering how to fill a variable with the output of e.g. shell-scripts once and reuse this, e.g. for needed include dirs

```
INCLUDES := -I`some-ext-config --incdir`
```

Using `:=` instead of `=` here makes this variable filled once so `some-ext-config` will only be called once (AFAIK this comes from plain `make`). Of course `INCLUDES` is the depreciated cousin of `AM_CPPFLAGS`, but would I have used that one instead, the shell script would have been called for each compile.

Using `INCLUDES` instead of `AM_CPPFLAGS` is an acceptable solution for me (though I imagine there might be portability issues), but I have no solution for e.g. LDFLAGS for a libtool library

```
libmylib_la_LDFLAGS := `some-ext-config --ldflags` # will always be evaluated
```

What is the general solution inside `automake` if I want to make sure these external tools are not called multiple times? I would like to stay away from using an obvious `AC_SUBST` in `configure.ac` since we have to make sure our packages can be build both from subdirectories (some `configure.ac` in there) and with an recursive make from the top-level and a `configure.ac` there which shouldn't need to know too much about the different subprojects.

Answer (score 2):

`:=` is GNU-make specific, so you are advised to use just `=` in automake. If you do not want to run the shell script everytime INCLUDES (or AM_CPPFLAGS, does not matter, it would occur with either), then run the script in configure.ac and use variable substitution via AC_SUBST. That is essentially what pkg-config would do — and come to speak of it, you could just use that instead of some-ext-config if there is a .pc file.

```
# configure.ac
libfoo_CPPFLAGS=$(some-ext-config --incdir);
libfoo_LIBS=$(some-ext-config --libs);
AC_SUBST([libfoo_CPPFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([libfoo_LIBS])

# Makefile.am
AM_CPPFLAGS = -Iwhatever ${libfoo_CPPFLAGS}
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_LDADD = ${libfoo_LIBS}
```

Comment: Hm, I wrote I would like to stay away from putting this into `configure.ac` for some external reasons.

Comment: @honk: then you will have to fix these external reasons (e.g. use `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`) or forgo writing portable Makefiles.

Comment: The external reason is that we want to be able to just add `AC_OUTPUT`s for the subdir `Makefile`s in the toplevel `Makefile.am`, but without calling `configure` in each and every subdir (which takes 5 times as long as our build). We only need to be portable to GNU make, do I understand correctly that there is no way to fill these automake variables only once?

Comment: @honk: I don't know of any.  Another option would be to `AC_SUBST` your variable from an autoconf macro that is shared by `configure.ac` and `subproject/configure.ac`.  The top-level `configure.ac` already has to know about the sub-project's Makefiles, so you could arrange to keep both the `AC_OUTPUT` and the needed `AC_SUBST` in the same file.

Comment: I meant `AC_CONFIG_FILES` instead of `AC_OUTPUT`, see my longer answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more lengthy explanation of what I suggested in a comment to jørgensen's answer.

I understand your top-level `configure.ac` must generate the makefiles of multiple sub-projects, and performs the required tests so that you don't have to run the `configure` in any subproject (a sub-`configure` serves only when you want to work on this particular sub-project).

In that case, you want to avoid duplicating as much stuff as possible from various `configure.ac`.  I suggest you factor all the code of the sub-`configure` that must also be performed by the top-level `configure` in an `m4` macro.  This includes tests, `AC_SUBSTS`, and `Makefile` declarations.

For instance using only one-subproject.  Here is a top-level `./configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([toplevel], [1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Werror])
SUB1_COMMON([sub1/])  dnl Stuff from the subproject
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

With `./Makefile.am`:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I sub1/m4
SUBDIRS = sub1
```

Now here is `sub1/configure.ac` for the sub-project:

```
AC_INIT([sub1], [1.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Werror])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
SUB1_COMMON
AC_OUTPUT
```

With `SUB1_COMMON` defined in `m4/common.m4`:

```
AC_DEFUN([SUB1_COMMON],
  [AC_SUBST([PYTHON3LIB], [`pkg-config --libs python3`])
   AC_CONFIG_FILES([$1Makefile])])
```

And finally `sub1/Makefile.am` is just:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
# Build something.
...
```

The `SUB1_COMMON` contains all the code you want to share between the two `configure.ac` files, and use argument `$1` to relocate the config files appropriately.  In this example, the variable `PYTHON3LIB` will be defined regardless of which `configure` were run.